# COM port detection in PC

Tags: usb

I am using Windows 10 in PC..

I have connected my lumia 820 with pc, is there any provision to check in which COM (e.g. COM3 , COM4 etc)port my modem/mobile has been connected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phones do not connect as a modem - they connect as an MTP device, so that you can copy media using you local friendly, favourite, choice of applications (for example, you might want to use Windows Explorer on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

**IF** the phone is placed in USB modem mode - and it's possible for a few of them, with hacks - then it will appear as a modem (once drivers are installed) in the usual places a modem would appear (which is Device Manager, possibly Devices and Printers, possibly Network Connections) and you could check it's Properties there to see which COM port it is using.

However, I don't know of any hack that will do that for a Lumia. If you want to connect your PC to the Internet through your phone, you need to turn on Internet Sharing in the phone, using either WiFi or Bluetooth, then connect your computer to the phone's WiFi network or pair the computer with the phone via Bluetooth.

Comment: I tried that device manager and tried to see its properties but there was nothing displaying of its COM port!!!

Comment: Because it's not in USB modem mode. As I said: "**IF** the phone is placed in USB modem mode..." That emphasis on the **IF** was there from the start. **You didn't do that, so of course there's no modem COM port**.